Quick question regarding charge densities in Electrodynamics
Consider the following equation
$$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$$
Taking divergence on both sides, we get
$$\vec{\nabla}.\vec{J}=\sigma \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
From here one uses the continuity equation to get the following differential equation for $\rho$
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}= - \sigma \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
However, instead of doing this, what if we use the fact that $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$ and plug this in,
$$\vec{\nabla}.(\rho\vec{v})=\sigma \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
I have two questions here. Firstly, does the above equation lead to any meaningful implication or conclusions ? Secondly, I've been led to believe that the $\rho$ on both sides of the equations are not the same thing. One is the density of total charge in the relevant gaussian surface, while the other one is density of moving charges that constitute the current i.e electrons or rather holes for conventional current.
In a current carrying wire for example, if the current is constant, I'm guessing that the $\rho$ on the LHS would remain, while the one on the RHS would be 0 as there are equal number of positive and negative charges flowing in opposite directions as the wire is neutral.
Are the above assertions correct ?

$\vec{J}=\rho\vec{v}$ does not hold, as you've realized; another way to see this is that in EM theory, $\rho=0$ in usual uniform conductors, so $\rho\vec{v}=0$, but we know current can flow in such conductors, so $\vec{J}$ is not necessarily zero. Instead, use $\vec{J}=\rho_m\vec{v}$, where $\rho_m$ is density of the moving charge.

Perhaps, your confusion comes from the way you're presenting the equations.
Let's redo your calculations but in a different way:
\begin{equation}
\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E} \\
\vec{\nabla} \cdot\vec{J} = \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\sigma \vec{E}) \\
\end{equation}
Let's integrate over a volume $V$ and use the divergence theorem
\begin{equation}
\oint_{V}(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J}) dV = \sigma\oint_{V} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E})dV \\
\Leftrightarrow \oint_{S}\vec{J} \cdot \vec{dS} = \sigma \oint_{S} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dS}
\end{equation}
Using the integral form of the Maxwell-Gauss equation, we have:
\begin{equation}
\oint_{S}\vec{J} \cdot \vec{dS} = \sigma \frac{Q_{int}}{\epsilon_0}
\end{equation}
where $Q_{int}$ represents the total electric charge present inside your material (depending from the volumetric charge distribution as $dQ_{int} = \rho dV$).
We also know that the electric current $I$ is simply the flux of the current density $\vec{J}$ over a closed surface:
\begin{equation}
\oint_{S}\vec{J} \cdot \vec{dS} = \sigma \frac{Q_{int}}{\epsilon_0} \\
\Leftrightarrow I = \sigma \frac{Q_{int}}{\epsilon_{0}}
\end{equation}
Which is just a reformulation of the first equation expressed with more easily understandable variables.
This equation simply means that the current $I$ is proportional to the total amount of charges contained in the material, which is linked to the charge volumetric density.
We can also put the previous equation in differential form (assuming $Q_{int}$ is not constant):
\begin{equation}
dI = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} dQ_{int} \\
dI = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \rho dV
\end{equation}
So basically what you did was just expressing the electric current with the total amount of charges instead of the voltage.
The fact that this result could lead to interesting applications totally depends on the problem you are trying to solve, so I will let you have the pleasure of filling in your specific problem data here.
